# Python - Connecting to random IPs and trying to get a response from the server

Tags: python, sockets, protocols, response

I have 4 peoples External IP's. I would like to connect to their IP and get a response from the server. It's weird because for every of the 4, no port on tcp protocol would connect, but every port on udp protocol, this is not the same for my own IP.

```
import socket, sys
socket.setdefaulttimeout(8.5)


del sys.argv[0]

def connect_send_receive(host, port):
      try:
         s = socket.socket((socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #On the Tcp protocol, no single port would connect to one of these 4 addresses.
         s.connect((host, port))
         s.send("I want you to dammit respond me something") #packet request says it all.
         s.recv(1024) #Server response with nothing. Error here.
      except:
         print("No response")

for connect in sys.argv:
       connect_send_receive(connect, 80)
```

My question is clear. 1. How do I get the server to give me a response, and after that. 2. why in 4 random people can I can only connect with udp protocol. I tried every port on tcp but no connection, and why with myself even if I go on a different IP I could connect to myself with tcp protocol.

Note: Http requests dont work on these 4 IPs.

Comment: Try using a simpler program like telnet or nc to see if the ports you're trying to use work or not.  Maybe it's a firewall problem.

Comment: Why *should* an arbitrary host accept a connection on a random port? Do you know any of these ports to be open, or why exactly are you expecting a response?

Comment: I used port scanners. "Consequently" those 4 IP had no tcp protocol ports, but on udp protocol, every number from range(1, 10000) was an open port.

Comment: I know different ports like: 21 FTP, 23 Telnet, 80 HTTP. But if none of those ports work, but this whole lot of udp protocol port works (including them), then this is why there is a question on this page.

Comment: UDP works differently. UDP is a connectionless protocol, so there's no clear open/closed states as there is with TCP. The only reliable information you can get from an UDP port is a response, which means that there's obviously something listening at that port. If you don't get a response, you know just as much as before.

Comment: Thank you!!!! :) So what can I do to get a proper response

Comment: unrelated: perhaps, you shouldn't reuse the same `socket` object. Move its definition inside `connect_send_receive()` function, to create a new object for each connection attempt. And call `socket.close()` in `finally` clause. You should also differentiate the errors (log them) e.g., you might pass incorrect `host` value.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a script made on the question, I'll fix that, oh and the host is correct. Normally, I would get gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed if they were not.

Comment: Well, pick a port (be it TCP or UDP) that you *know to be open*, and send a packet that that conforms to the protocol for the service on that port (DNS, HTTP, ...). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to build a port scanner?

Comment: Already have built an tcp port scanner.. udp one would be nice, but no. 1. I would like to send these IP's packets. 2. I would like to know, how and why.

Comment: You *are* sending packets. But why do you think you should get a response? If you shout at a stranger in the street, you might or might not get a response. But there's nothing *you* can do to make him respond if he doesn't want to.

Comment: Did you not just say, we can know if that port is valid via udp, if we get a response? Please respect my education :/

Comment: No, I said **if** you get a response, you can know for sure that the port is open. If you don't get a response (which is far more likely), you don't know anything. Again, what are you trying to do? Yes, send packets to those IPs and get a response, but *why*?

Comment: Because, these 4 I want to make communication with. The people holding these IPs are people I know and have allowed me to send packets to them.

Comment: So what UDP services are they running?

Comment: I don't know. The reason I tried udp because no ports where open on tcp for these IPs. I tried using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.

Comment: Well, then you can't. Unless there's a service running that accepts incoming connections/requests, you can't just communicate with them.

Comment: So how would I communicate with them? Would they need to port forward or some method likewise?

Comment: They would need to start some sort of service that allows to communicate over. Could be anything (in theory), from IRC, a mail server (SMTP), Skype, some LAN instant messaging service, ... And you then would need to speak that protocol - which is MUCH more complicated than just sending an ASCII string.

Comment: If you want a *really simple* example for an UDP echo client and server, have a look at this: http://pymotw.com/2/socket/udp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a connection-based protocol.  A specific "[handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)" must happen to establish that connection.  If no service is listening on the TCP port you try to connect to (or if a firewall is filtering connections to that port and your host doesn't pass the filter), then you will simply get a TCP reset from the system that rejects the request.

UDP is a connectionless protocol.  There is no response when a packet is sent unless the application on the server is designed to send one.  If the UDP port is filtered or no service is listening on it, the packet is quietly dropped -- with no indication to the sender.

As for your code, SOCK_DGRAM is a datagram (UDP) socket.  You need to use a STREAM socket to connect to a TCP service.